# Why isn't the KryoSerializer enabled by default in SPARK?

Tags: apache-spark

All the blogs I have read state that the KryoSerializer is better than the default java serializer. So, why isn't it enabled by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after watching some talks on these default settings, it appears that many default settings in spark are chosen to give the best out of the box experience for a typical 1st user trying to run something on their laptop to get a feel for what Spark is.

When people go to the trouble of worrying about performance and deploying to real clusters, most people have already decided to invest some time to seeing what it can do for the problem space. Then, they can spend the time deciding if something like kyro is good for them, given the extra code required to register the classes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have found only this:

> The only reason Kryo is not the default is because of the custom registration requirement, but we recommend trying it in any network-intensive application.

From the official Spark [Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization).

Comment: Thanks - "custom registration requirement" - do you know this means?

Comment: Of course. You can see it in a code example [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization). Without Kryo you only need to implement the java.io.Serializable interface. But when you use Kryo, then you have to do more than this.

Comment: Many thanks - if I am using pyspark, does it help at all?

Comment: It depends on what you do in Spark. I would try it out with and without kryo. Additionally I have found [this](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/using-Kryo-with-pyspark-td4229.html). You can also use Datasets instead of RDDs in some cases. There your are able to use Encoders. They are faster than Kryo.

Comment: @SimonSchiff do you have link for Encoders being faster than Kryo please?

Comment: Yes I have: [link](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html)